# Redirect to paypal checkout page

Tags: php, html, paypal

I'm trying to implement paypal into my website. So what i have is a form and after submiting that form i would like to redirect user to paypal page, like this:

```
if($validator->check()){
  //do some things like adding data to database, etc
  //redirect user to paypal here
}
```

how can i do this?

**EDIT:** i can't just use header, i also need to send my encrypted data to paypal, here is the form that i would use if i would be using paypal provided button: http://pastebin.com/w65LkmBE

Comment: This is a really vague question.  What are you trying to accomplish with paypal?  What are they paying for?  What data do you want to send to Paypal?

Comment: it's quite simple user fills form on my page then i do some checking for errors if everything is fine i want to redirect to paypal so they could pay to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You should use JS (AJAX) for this.
If the form method would be GET and not POST, than that would be real.

Comment: You have form with <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">. User click on submit button with "onclick=checkThisForm()". Your JS function "checkThisForm()" validate user input herself or with AJAX response from PHP script. If user input is valid, than user with form data goes to Paypal.

Comment: All details of the implementation is difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1):

if you did not echoed anything :

```
header("Location: http://paypal.com/...")
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `exit();` after it.